# Excel multi variables and outputs

Tags: excel

First of all, I am not VBA user. 
And I have written a very complex Excel worksheet internally correlated with functions. 
Let's say x as the value that I type in and y as some numbers I am trying to get eventually as a result of calculations.
So what I am trying to do is changing x values while saving previous y values.
It would nice if I could have y values in different cells depending on x values.
For example, if x is 3, y returns in cell B1, and if x is 4 y returns in cell B2.
It would be appreciated if anyone could suggest an idea for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest and say that based on the limited information in your question,  this is the sort of thing that VBA makes easier.  With VBA, you have far more control over how output from calculations are displayed,  so 'recording' results in a formated (historical) fashion is much easier.

Consider a typical Excel Based Invoice system (I'm talking about freebies to download).  You have a worksheet that looks like an invoice - it has boxes for text, lines for items, quantity, cost.  It totals it all up at the bottom (all using formulas).  You can manually print the invoice and that's fine.  But you want to record the data to view again later?  Rather than 'copy' the worksheet,  most of the examples you'll find have a button (with VBA code), to store just the data (without the 'invoice' formatting) on a separate sheet.

Whilst you said that you're not a VBA person, you haven't specifically said that the solution must be a formula.  Therefore,  I have to say that in my opinion, the solution is definitely VBA and that's where you should be looking.  Happy to create some example code to point you in the right direction if you agree.